# Nested to nested meta query freezes in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying nested query to nested query.. the problem is that when a have multiple query conditions the query freezes..
This is my code..

```
array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            array( 'key' => 'bedrooms', 'value' => intval($bedrooms), 'compare' => '=' )
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array( 'key' => 'bedrooms', 'value' => intval($bedrooms), 'compare' => '>=' ),
            array( 'key' => 'up_to_bedrooms', 'value' => intval($bedrooms), 'compare' => '<=' ),
            array( 'key' => 'up_to_bedrooms', 'value' => '', 'compare' => '!=' )
        )
    ),
    array(
        //another meta query
    )
);
```

What can I do?

Comment: please elaborate what you are trying to ask currently it is not  understandable

Comment: querying meta like this is super slow/expensive. Your query hasn't frozen, it's just taking a veeeery long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bedrooms and up_to_bedrooms are key from custom fields..
I made the second one also mandatory to not have so complexed meta queries.. and it works fine right now as it is...

here is the new query

```
array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array( 'key' => 'status_0_bedrooms', 'value' => intval($bedrooms), 'compare' => '<=', 'type' => 'NUMERIC' ),
        array( 'key' => 'status_0_up_to_bedrooms', 'value' => intval($bedrooms), 'compare' => '>=', 'type' => 'NUMERIC' )
    ),
    array(
        //another meta query
    )
);
```